# Query malfunction in SQLServerCE using with VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am working on a project, where my target is to automate the fee-system of a school.
I am implementing the project in VB.NET 2012 and using SQLServerCE for handling data.

My situation is like this :

I have two tables namely : 'feecollection' and 'StudentDetails'

The columns of the table feecollection are as follows [image: feecollection]

Similarly, the columns of the table StudentDetails are as follows [image: StudentDetails]

Now I want to find out the names of student(s) who are defaulters.
I am doing the filtering on the basis of Name, Months and the defaulter fields.

Logic : The name of the students who are in fee collection for a given month have paid, so defaults are all names which are in StudentDetails but not in feecollection whose defaulter field is '1' (1 indicates that they have paid).

My query :

```sql
select StudentDetails.Name where StudentDetails.Name not in
 (Select feecollection.Name, feecollection.Month, feecollection.defaulter, 
   StudentDetails.Name from feecollection 
   inner join StudentDetails on feecollection.Name = StudentDetails.Name 
   where StudentDetails.Name = 'def' and feecollection.month = 'January' 
   and feecollection.defaulter = '1'
```

But this query is not working properly.
Where did I go wrong on this ?

Comment: `month = 'January'`? This query will work great (well, once you learn proper syntax) while the application is less than a year old, but you're going to need smarter date range queries beyond that.

Comment: The january is just for test. In the application, the month is being selected from a combobox :)

Comment: But still, they're going to pick "January" from a list? Which January?

Comment: January of the current Year. The code is still very pre-mature and year will be added later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the defaulter field is '0' or the feecollection record is missing when the student has NOT payed, I would use a SQL statement something like this.

```sql
SELECT StudentDetails.Name FROM StudentDetails 
    LEFT JOIN feecollection ON StudentDetails.Name = feecollection.Name 
    AND feecollection.Payment_For_Month = 'Jan' 
    WHERE feecollection.defaulter = '0' OR feecollection.defaulter IS NULL;
```

This way you should get all records in StudentDetails where the matching feecollection record either has '0' in defaulter, or is not present.

**EDIT**

If you still want to use the IN operator this statement should do it:

```sql
SELECT StudentDetails.Name FROM StudentDetails WHERE
    StudentDetails.Name NOT IN 
    (SELECT feecollection.Name FROM feecollection 
    WHERE feecollection.Payment_For_Month = 'Feb' 
    AND feecollection.defaulter = '1')
```

I've tested this out on a simplified dataset:

StudentDetails:

```
Name    Class    Section        
------------------------
Adam    101      Sect1
Bob     101      Sect
Charlie 101      Sect2
```

feecollection:

```
Name    Payment_For_Month    defaulter
--------------------------------------
Adam    Jan                  1
Adam    Feb                  1
Bob     Jan                  1
```

With this data the top statement returns only Charlie, while the second statement returns Bob and Charlie.

Comment: This query is shooting an exception. The query I used is : "SELECT StudentDetails.Name FROM StudentDetails LEFT JOIN feecollection ON StudentDetails.Name = feecollection.Name AND feecollection.Payment_For_Month = 'January' WHERE feecollection.defaulter = '0' OR feecollection.defaulter IS NULL;"

Comment: More importantly, I want to base my search on the Names that are present in feecollection and have their defaulter as '1'. But either way, an exception is being thrown.

Comment: I've fixed the exception problem. Here is the fixed query :                 "SELECT StudentDetails.Name, StudentDetails.Class, StudentDetails.Section, StudentDetails.Roll_Number, StudentDetails.Parent_Name, StudentDetails.Parent_Phone FROM StudentDetails " & "LEFT JOIN feecollection ON StudentDetails.Name = feecollection.Name " & "AND feecollection.Payment_For_Month = '" & month & "' WHERE feecollection.defaulter = '1' AND feecollection.Name = '" & sstr & "';" . But this doesn't produce the results.

Comment: @Priyabrata I've updated the answer. Is this closer to what you are searching for? In the first statement I only changed the Month to Payment_For_Month. If this still fails: Which kind of exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes, your query is throwing an exception. "Column name = 'Payment_For_Month' is invalid. This is the message in the exception window. However, I modified the query a little : "Select * From StudentDetails where name not in (SELECT StudentDetails.Name FROM StudentDetails Right JOIN feecollection ON feecollection.Name = StudentDetails.Name where feecollection.defaulter = '1' AND feecollection.Payment_For_Month = '" & month & "');"
This query works fine. However, I couldn't find the problem with your query as the column, 'Payment_For_Month' DOES EXIST!